# Tensorflowでテンソルの要素のうち0以上のものの和を計算したい

Tags: python, tensorflow

```
t = tf.constant([[1,-1,2,-3],[3,4,-3,2],[2,-1,-2,-3],[2,2,3,1]])
```

があるとき、tの要素の中から値が正のものだけを選んで和を出したいのですがどうすればよろしいでしょうか。
簡単に言うと下記のようなことをtensorflowでしたいです。

```
sum = 0
for i in len(t):
  for j in len(t[0]):
    if t[i][j]>0:
      sum += t[i][j]
=> sum == 22
```

何卒よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

```
# 各要素に対してゼロ行列と比較して最大値をとれば負の数を除外できる
z = tf.constant(0, shape=[4, 4], dtype=tf.int32)
abs = tf.maximum(t, z)

# 全要素の総和をとる
result = tf.reduce_sum(abs)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
condition = tf.greater(t,0)
sum = tf.reduce_sum(tf.select(condition, t, tf.zeros_like(t)))
```

でできることがわかりました。

tf.selectなら古いバージョンでも新しいバージョンでも動く気がします。
比較的新しいバージョンを使っている方は以下でも可能っぽいです。

```
sum = tf.reduce_sum(tf.where(condition, t, tf.zeros_like(t)))
```

※私は0.8.0を使っているので、このようなwhereの使い方はできません。